# LAU Button function

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a 2nd button that runs another command that's not kill the first button does suicide i tried the 2nd button so it disables the hud but it also suicides like the first button? can someone help also i want the 2nd button to toggle on and off instead of having to create 2 buttons on/off thanks.

```
if (SERVER) then

end

if (CLIENT) then
    local midW, midH = ScrW() / 2, ScrH() / 2
    local function OpenMyProject()
        local MyProject = vgui.Create( "DFrame" )
        MyProject:SetSize(500,350)
        MyProject:SetPos(50,50)
        MyProject:SetTitle("Gaming Reborn Menu")
        MyProject:SetVisible(true)
        MyProject:SetDraggable(true)
        MyProject:SetBackgroundBlur(false)
        MyProject:MakePopup()
        MyProject.Paint = function()
        draw.RoundedBox( 8, 0, 0, MyProject:GetWide(), MyProject:GetTall(), Color( 0, 0, 0, 150 ) )
        end


        local MyLabel = vgui.Create( "DLabel", MyProject )
        MyLabel:SetPos( 90, 30 )
        MyLabel:SetSize( 150, 20)

        local MyButton = vgui.Create( "DButton", MyProject )
        MyButton:SetText( "Suicide" )
        MyButton:SetPos(5,27)
        MyButton:SetSize(150,50)
        MyButton:SetColor( Color( 0, 110, 160 ) )
        MyButton.DoClick = function()
            RunConsoleCommand (  "kill" )
            end
        local MyButton2 = vgui.Create( "DButton", MyProject )
        MyButton2:SetText( "HUD" )
        MyButton2:SetPos(5,67)
        MyButton2:SetSize(150,50)
        MyButton2:SetColor( Color( 0, 110, 160 ) )
        MyButton2.DoClick = function()
            RunConsoleCommand (  "cl_drawhud "0"" )
        end
    end
    concommand.Add( "openproject", OpenMyProject )
end
```

Comment: What it has to do with [tag:jquery]?

Comment: i couldn't tag lau and jquery popped up :/